# GWT set cursor to a position (x,y)

Tags: gwt, cursor, cursor-position

in GWT, Is it possible to set the cursor position to a location (x,y) (top,left) ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you referring to the mouse cursor?  If so, browsers don't provide an API for setting the position of the mouse cursor.

If you're talking about a text insertion caret in a `TextArea` or similar widget, you can use `TextBoxBase.setCursorPos()` to set the caret to a particular offset within the text.

Answer (score 0):

Setting mouse cursor is not possible in JS, due to security. Think of entering a site which suddenly starts to move your mouse for you ... and possibly click ads on this site. Would you add such feature to browser?